# How to check if a column is empty in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an order table with the `user_fk` column and `invoice` column. Let's just say I want to get an order instance that is related to my user but with an empty invoice column. How do I do that with mysql?

perhaps this will illustrate it

```
"SELECT * FROM order WHERE user_fk = $user_fk AND invoice === false;"
```

edit: invoice column is an interger

Comment: Unclear, What do you mean `with an empty` on invoice column?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Does "empty" include a string consisting of whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE user_fk = $user_fk AND invoice is null or invoice = '';
```

Try this if `invoice` supports null

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the invoice column is null or length of column is 0.

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE user_fk = $user_fk AND (invoice is null or len(invoice)=0);
```